# Should I upgrade to 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: upgrade, asus

I got hold of a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed. I am a Mac user and have found pretty easy to navigate Ubuntu. Now, before I get deep onto it I am wondering should I upgrade to 16.04 LTS first? 
The machine is:

```
ASUS- Extensa-5635Z
Memory - 2GB
Procesor - Pentium® Dual-Core CPUT4400@2.20GHZx2
Graphics - Mobile Intel GM45 Express Chipset x 86/MMX/SSE2
OS type - 32-bit
Disk 250GB
```

Comment: I guess it's a typo, title states 16.04

Comment: As that computer seems slightly underpowered, I'd suggest installing Xubuntu instead of regular Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind" 16.04 still supports 32-bit

Comment: Ok let me rephrase it then:  no. Memory: not good enough. Dual core: not good enough.32-bit? Why? Your system supports 64-bit. "64bit with SpeedStep working (sometimes BIOS-update needed)" (source http://www.linlap.com/acer_extensa_5635z ) you might need  BIOS update.  But stick to a more compatible OS. XUbuntu or LUbuntu.

Comment: Thank You Rinzwind, your answer makes sense, I expected that this machine is a bit under powered, that's why asked the question in the first place. Why 32-Bit ? That's what was installed, I should definitely switch to 64 and try. As I said, I have no experience with LINUX and unfortunately no LINUX Users Club nowhere near me, so I'll see how deep I'll be able to dig. XUbuntu-LUbuntu ?!?!?! Thank you  again

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You're welcome to notify me here with a link to your new question so I may have a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always a good practice to use last version of softwares and operation systems unless it's somehow is not possible for you or your situation.

It's been a while that Ubuntu adopted systemd and all further versions will came out with systemd unless something magically happens. so it's better to use 16.04 now and learn to work with systemd from beginning.

The other thing you should consider is the support. 
Ubuntu 14.04 end of life is April 2019 while 16.04 is April 2021. From: [Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

If you want to don't touch your OS for a long time, enjoy stability and more up to dated softwares, I suggest updating to 16.04.

If you don't have any important installed package, config, etc. I even suggest a fresh install of 16.04.